# Sending large canvas image to server

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, canvas, base64

I am uploading a large image and cropping it and converting the cropped canvas to base64. I am passing the base64 data to server using ajax.

```
var pic = result.toDataURL("image/png");
pic = pic.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: Sitepath + '/PhotoContest/UploadPhoto',
    data: '{ "ImageData" : "' + pic + '" }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
    }
});
```

In C# MVC, I have written the action like below.

```
[WebMethod()]
public void UploadPhoto(string ImageData)
{   
    Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    string FileName = "Photo_" + unixTimestamp+".jpg";
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads"), FileName);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working when I upload small images. If I upload image more than 2 MB. I am getting the below error.

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
```

Though I have written these below three in the web.config.

```
<system.web.extensions> 
    <scripting> 
        <webServices> 
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/> 
        </webServices>
    </scripting> 
</system.web.extensions>

<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" /> <!--1GB-->
</system.web>    

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!--1GB-->
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Not certain if this will fix it, but the `maxAllowedContentLength` is a `uint`, so it's max value is 4,294,967,295. (The value passed into it is way above that.)

Comment: It seems the error is somewhere beyond it.